# AttributeError: 'StreamingPullFuture' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to write a job which reads messages from subscriber and output it to bigquery.
Python version used is 3.6 .

I am receiving error as below while executing the code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "subscriber.py", line 73, in <module>
    receive_data(project_id, subscription_name )
  File "subscriber.py", line 59, in receive_data
    future = subscription.open(callback)
AttributeError: 'StreamingPullFuture' object has no attribuate 'open'
```

Subscriber.py code is as below:

```
import base64
import json
import time

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import pubsub

project_id = "PROJECT_NAME"
subscription_name = "SUBSCRIPTION_NAME"
DATASET_ID = 'DATASET_NAME'
TABLE_ID = 'test_data'

def write_data_to_bq(dataset_id, table_id, data):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)

    errors = client.insert_rows(table, data)
    if not errors:
        print('Loaded {} row(s) into {}:{}'.format(len(data), dataset_id, table_id))
    else:
        print('Errors:')
        for error in errors:
            print(error)

# decodes the message from PubSub
def collect_data(data):
    inputdata = []
    stream = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data)
    twraw = json.loads(stream)
    localmessages = twraw.get('messages')
    for message in localmessages:
        inputdata.append(message['data'])

    write_data_to_bq(DATASET_ID, TABLE_ID, inputdata)

# receive data from topic
def receive_data(project, subscription_name):
    subscriber = pubsub.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))
        collect_data(message.data)
        message.ack()

    subscription = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))

    future = subscription.open(callback)
    try:
        future.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print(
            'Listening for messages on {} threw an Exception: {}'.format(
                subscription_name, e))
        raise


    while True:
        time.sleep(60)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    receive_data(project_id, subscription_name)
```

As per the google docs I see that the package imported is pubsub_v1 so I replaced `pubsub` with 
`from google.cloud import pubsub_v1`

But nothing seems to be working even after the changes.

Also tried to make changes to requirements.txt as it seems to be version issue. 
Current requirements.txt is as :

```
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
google-api-core==1.14.3
google-auth==1.6.3
google-cloud-bigquery==1.20.0
google-cloud-core==1.0.3
google-cloud-pubsub==1.0.2
google-resumable-media==0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.24.1
idna==2.8
protobuf==3.10.0
pyasn1==0.4.7
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.25.6
```

Can someone guide on this?

Comment: What were you hoping `subscription.open(callback)` would do? You already gave the callback to the subscription, with `subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)`, and that call already gave you a future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)` call *itself* returns the future object, there is no need for a separate `.open()` call. Just assign that result to `future`:

```
future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))

try:
    future.result()
except Exception as e:
    print(
        'Listening for messages on {} threw an Exception: {}'.format(
            subscription_name, e))
    raise
```

There is [no `.open()` method in the subscriber client API](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/search.html?q=open), you already set up the subscription with `subscriber.subscribe()`.